# C# Application being blocked by Anti-Virus?

Tags: c#, virus, malware

I have a Payroll System that is written using Visual C# Express. I have actually finished coding it already and published it. But whenever I install it on the laptop it is being blocked by Avast! Antivirus as suspicious and stops the process. After that the applciation cannot be started event though it was installed saying that a file is missing. It has this in its `details` :

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.296
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.296 (RTMGDR.030319-2900)
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/John%20Jayson/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start%20Menu/Programs/IT%20Box%20Incorporated/Payroll%20System.appref-ms%7C

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\John Jayson\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\IT Box Incorporated\Payroll System.appref-ms| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Activation failed.
        + The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [2/15/2013 12:39:05 PM] : Activation of C:\Users\John Jayson\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\IT Box Incorporated\Payroll System.appref-ms| has started.
    * [2/15/2013 12:39:05 PM] : Performing necessary update check as specified by the deployment.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [2/15/2013 12:39:05 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (Activation)
        - Activation failed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowShortcut(String shortcutFile, String& errorPageUrl, TempFile& deployFile)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        - The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

So before the window saying `Application cannot be started` pops up A notification windows from Avast says that it is a `Win32:Evo-gen` threat.

What should I do?

Comment: How are you installing it? Click Once? What happens if you white list it in the AV software and try running, does it still error? Are you sure that nothing bad got placed into the source code? Have you run a full AV scan of the system?

Comment: Also looks like lots of false positives from anything .Net related: http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=113984.0, make sure you are up to date as it looks like it was fixed end of Janurary

Comment: I am scanning the system where I coded and published it now. I know that nothing bad is in its source code it just accesses its database which is an acess database. It is Click Once

Comment: It is in white list of Autosandbox of Avast! But then it is being blocked by the File System Shield

Comment: Dang so what should I do?

Comment: Are you referencing other DLLs into the project?

Comment: I think I have referenced one dll that was supposed to give me additional controls but then I wasn't able to use it but I just left it there. I'll try removing it and republ,ishing

Comment: Did you make sure to update Avast? There was apparently an issue that was resolved on Jan 31st, 2013 according to the post I linked above.

Comment: I updated it already. Removing the dll and republishing didn't make any difference

Comment: Is this issue because of Avast itself? does this mean if the laptop have other antiviruses it would not be detected as virus/malware?

Comment: Maybe the following article will help you http://malwaretips.com/blogs/win32evo-gen-susp-virus/. You can also use VirusTotal to scan you exe and then send the report to Avast. See the following post on Avast forum http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=124051.0

Comment: Are you also using an obfuscator tool? A few years ago I had my AntiVir giving alerts while the the Xenocode Obfuscator was in process was running on my assemblies. Whitelisting finally solved it.

Answer (score 1):

It also  happened with me, I have project in c#, I am using external Ribbon35 control in my project which has option in tabs like creating, scanning, processing etc. When I added 4 new tabs and added buttons on tabs it suddenly shows [Win32:Evo-gen] and exe was blocked. Please remember I did not rename Tab Names instead they were on its default names like [RibbonTab1, captiontext = Scanning] I though Antivirus would have thinking this as malicious behavior from my application, I rename all tabs as like its behavior and problem gone. 
(May be hackers don't care about naming controls as their behaviors)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem while working on a project using VB.NET, Then I changed my recent updates back to identify the problem. The problem was with an "Insert" statement where I used below code to get the date value from a Datetimepicker Control directly.

`dtpJD.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")`

Then I replaced it with a Variable in Insert statement and everything was fine.

`parJDDate = dtpJD.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 0):

found one clue..
-when my application run from folder with foreign characters in the name
then Avast will block it. 
-After I renamed folder to contains only eng chars. Problem was solved.

Answer (score -2):

Buddy, it detects as a virus becouse it contains payment, and it thinks you got a ransomware, you can add to exclusions i think, but i never used avast, it's not the best antivirus, if u want a free antivirus with good protection use comodo, or if u want best: kaspersky, or you should use another method, but i prefer to uninstall avast and install a better antivirus software, check the site of the [AV Test](http://www.av-test.org/en/tests/home-user/windows-8/janfeb-2013/)
and choose the best protection level what you need

Regards